# Adding a persistence unit in JNDI for EJB modules

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am working on a simple EJB module using sample code. I am trying to implement CURD operations through a SOAP web service. I have a persistence unit defined in `persistence.xml`.

Here is the code for my implementation. The problem is that I cannot create an instance of `PersistenceService` because the persistence unit name is not present in the JNDI listings.

If, instead of using code injection, I use

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PU_NAME);
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

the code runs, but then the transaction is managed by the container. I was reading through some tutorials and they mentioned that, in this scenario, if the user wants to roll the transaction back later, he cannot do so.

What can I do instead?

#### users class

```
@WebService()
@Stateless()
public class users {
public users()
{

}

/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "addUser")
public Integer addUser(
        @WebParam(name = "UserName") final String UserName,
        @WebParam(name = "LastName") final String LastName) {

        DatabaseEntityManager dem = new DatabaseEntityManager();
        Integer result = null;
        try
        {
        result = dem.addUser(UserName, LastName, false);
        dem.commitTx();
        return result;
        } catch(Exception E)
        {
        }
 return new Integer(-1);
 }
```

#### DatabaseEntityManager class

```
public class DatabaseEntityManager {
    PersistenceService ps_bck = null;
    public DatabaseEntityManager()
    {

    }

    public SiteUsers addUser(
        String Username,
        String LastName, boolean commit) throws Exception
    {
        AppUser appUser = new appUser(UserName, LastName);
        //AppUser is an entity class 

        PersistenceService ps = PersistenceService.getInstance();
        try
        {
            ps.beginTx();
            EntityManager em = ps.getEntityManager();
            em.persist(appUser);
            if (commit)
                ps.commitTx();
            else
                ps_bck  = ps;
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            ps.rollbackTx();
        }
        finally
        {
            ps.close();
        }

        return appUser.getId();
    }

    void commitTx() throws Exception
    {
        try
        { 
            ps_bck.commitTx();
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            throw E;
        }
        finally
        {
            ps_bck =null;
        }
    }
}
```

#### PersistenceService class — borrowed from sample code generated by NetBeans

```
public class PersistenceService {
    private static String DEFAULT_PU = "pers-ejbPU";

    private static ThreadLocal<PersistenceService> instance = new ThreadLocal<PersistenceService>() {
        @Override
        protected PersistenceService initialValue() {
            return new PersistenceService();
        }
    };

    private EntityManager em;
    private UserTransaction utx;

    private PersistenceService() {
        try {
            //This code runs 
            // EntityManagerFactory emf = ersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(DEFAULT_PU);
            // em = emf.createEntityManager();

            //This code throws an exception
            this.em = (EntityManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/persistence/"+ DEFAULT_PU);
            this.utx = (UserTransaction) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of PersistenceService.
     *
     * @return an instance of PersistenceService
     */
    public static PersistenceService getInstance() {
        return instance.get();
    }

    private static void removeInstance() {
        instance.remove();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of EntityManager.
     *
     * @return an instance of EntityManager
     */
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    /**
     * Begins a resource transaction.
     */
    public void beginTx() {
        try {
            utx.begin();
            em.joinTransaction();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Commits a resource transaction.
     */
    public void commitTx() {
        try {
            utx.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Rolls back a resource transaction.
     */
    public void rollbackTx() {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes this instance.
     */
    public void close() {
        removeInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your persistence.xml has an entry

```
 <persistence-unit name="PU_NAME" transaction-type="JTA">
```

In your PersistenceService class, add the annotation:

```
@PersistenceContext (name = "PU_NAME") private EntityManager em;
```